# How to direct users to my android app store

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked and answered before.
But when I try the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); 
intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=your.game.package.name")); 
startActivity(intent);
```

I get the message "the method parse(String) is undefined for the type String.

Could it be I need to import something? I have imported android.net.URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. You have to import `android.net.Uri`. CamelCase.

EDIT:
If I added `String Uri = null;` above your snippet I got exactly same error as you have.

Comment: I know. I can't understand it. I have imported android.net.Uri and  eclipse still underlines parse in red with the error message I gave. I should say those are the only 3 lines of code I have used (in a switch statement). Maybe I should be adding other code elsewhere?

Comment: It looks like you have `String` named `Uri`. I got exactly same error as you have if i created `String Uri = null;` line above your snippet.

Comment: Wow! I am so grateful you spotted that! I would never have found it.